# No value given for one or more required parameters. during paramatized search

Tags: vb.net, parameters, ms-access-2007

I am trying a paramatized search to prevent sql injection. However the error
"No value given for one or more required parameters". comes

```
     Dim sql As String
    Call connect()
    con.Open()
    sql = "Select * from Records where Customer_ID=@CustomerID"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Txt_Customer_ID.Text)
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Txt_Customer_ID.Text = dr(0)
        Txt_Customer_Name.Text = dr(1)
        Txt_Customer_Contact.Text = dr(2)
        Txt_Delivery_Method.Text = dr(3)
        Txt_Reference.Text = dr(4)
    End While

    con.Close()
```

The Customer_ID field in the database is a text type and I need to know how to finish this search without running into the error

Comment: I am doing this in a test database that has only one table and I have copy pasted the table and field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer! Thank you to everyone who tried

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Txt_Customer_ID.Text)
```

line must be below

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
```

Here is the code that works

```
 Dim sql As String
    Call connect()
    con.Open()
    sql = "Select * from Records where Customer_ID=@CustomerID"

    cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Records where Customer_ID=@CustomerID", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Txt_Customer_ID.Text)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Txt_Customer_ID.Text = dr(0)
        Txt_Customer_Name.Text = dr(1)
        Txt_Customer_Contact.Text = dr(2)
        Txt_Delivery_Method.Text = dr(3)
        Txt_Reference.Text = dr(4)
    End While

    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the order like this

```
     cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Txt_Customer_ID.Text)
```

Comment: Thank you but can you show how to do other way. I am learning how to do that for now.

Comment: What you mean "how to do other way?"??

Comment: The method in the question. Is there an error in the code I have done. like missing characters like '' or ""  .

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Txt_Customer_ID.Text)
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con).      Do new inislize before create parameter